# Like button without refreshing a Page using jQuery in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-models

I have a view that controls my like and dislike functions perfectly. But I want a scenario were authenciated users can like a page without refreshing the whole Page. Here's my code for better understanding... Thanks in advance

My View:

```
def like_post(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
        post_obj = Blog.objects.get(id=post_id)

        if user in post_obj.liked.all():
            post_obj.liked.remove(user)
        else:
            post_obj.liked.add(user)

        like,created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, post_id=post_id)

        if not created:
            if like.value=='Like':
                like.value='Dislike'
            else:
                like.value = 'Like'

        like.save()
        return redirect('blog')
```

Models:

```
LIKE_CHOICES = {
    ('Like', 'Like'),
    ('Dislike','Dislike')
} 
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES, default='Like', max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

My HTML

```
Html
<div class="like-section">
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  <form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{blog.id}}">
    {% if user not in blog.liked.all %}
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" id="like" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
    {% else %}
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" id="like" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i> </button>
    {% endif %}
  </form>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
   <small class="like-count{{blog.id}}">{{blog.liked.all.count}} Likes</small>
```

And lastly my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(event){
        $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var post_id = $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              url: '{% url "like_post" %}',
              data:{'id':post_id, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':'{{csrf_token}}'},
              success: function(data){
                $('#like-section').html(data)
              }
              });
        });
        });  
  </script>
```

I still don't understand what to do. My jQuery code only stops my like button not to be clickable when I try to click, asides that, nothing more important it does

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make your button like:

```
<a class="your custom style" href="javascript:void(0);">ICON</a>
```

Comment: So as I can see your form does send you to your other codes. Second option would be to make check option and check if the state of them is checked or not then if it is send to a form?

Comment: Can you come again please.. I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Make 2 check boxes (like up, like down) and check if they are checked or not. Try to do it without form so it will never refresh page.

Comment: But if you look at my view.py, I've  if request.method=="POST".. So removing the form, I doubt if my like function will run, or what do you think.. thanks

Comment: Try to remove your form in html and tun your function trough href link. Tell me if works

Answer (score 0):

Change your button to an anchor tag, like this:

```
<a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-postid="{{blog.id}}">Like</a>
```

And then change your jquery as follows:

```
var post_id = $(this).data('postid');
```